# Rails 3: has_many through controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through

I've got a Rails 3 app setup that I use for driving an API, with a `has_many through` association working. I know that to setup the association I should use `device.favourites.create(object)` and that works fine when I run it either within the web app, or on the console but I don't know how I should use it for the controller action for a `json` request. Should I `POST` to the join model (`Favourites`) or one of the models at the end (`Device`/`Store`)? If I `POST` to the one of the models at either end, should I calling the `.create` method with controller `create` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using the join model to accept a params hash containing both the variables it links against. It was the cleanest way to do it and it seems to work fine.